# x86 pointless piece of small code or?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I have a project assignment in school which is the infamous x86 bomb. At one point in the code, the compiler does this instruction:

> mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax

followed by

> and    $0xf,%eax

then puts %eax back into where it was taken from with this instruction:

> mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)

Do you think it is something done by the compiler automaticly or is it something done by the instructor to just confuse me and make it harder for me to figure out what's going on? Because from what I understand, this portion of the code does absolutely nothing. Takes a 4 byte word from the stack, uses and instruction on its last 4 bits with the binary number "1111" and puts it back on to the same spot on the stack. Which seems kind of pointless to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: It changes the value on the stack, so why would that be pointless?

Comment: `andl $0xf, 0x1c(%esp)` would be somewhat faster (2 fused-domain uops instead of 3).  I'm sure the surrounding code is confusing and noisy, because that looks like compiler output from `-O0`.  Even old gcc and clang [use `and` with a memory destination at any other optimization level](https://godbolt.org/g/PXhjnI).  **So you're probably looking at a ton of load/modify/store, reload/modify/store instructions.  This is why nobody finds `-O0` compiler output readable**, and `-Og -fverbose-asm` or even `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize` output is much preferable for human-readability.

Comment: `and $0xf,%eax` doesn't *use an instruction on its last 4 bits*. It actually masks out all but the last 4 bits of the contents of `%eax`. The contents of `%eax` are then different (potentially). The next instruction puts the new value of `%eax` back on the stack. So if the stack value retrieved was initially, `$0xA5A5A5A5` then the new value will be `$0x00000005`.

Comment: @RossRidge I'm confused as to how it changes the value on the stack. If you use and operation on something and one of the operands is 1, isn't the output always going to be the same as the second operand?

Comment: It's AND'ing all 32 individual bits of EAX with the corresponding 32 individual bits of the immediate operand 0x0000000f. Only 4 bits of that value are 1, so only 4 bits of the value in EAX remain unchanged. See lurker's comment above for an example of what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props to @lurker and @RossRidge , the instruction;

> and $0xf, %eax

is used to mask all but the last 4 bits of the contents of %eax.